# Why Android Studio throws me an error when setting a nine patch image as a spinner background

Tags: java, android, background-image, spinner, nine-patch

You see, I do not know why it happens but when I set a nine patch image as a spinner background and I rebuild or clean the project, Android Studio (v2.2.3)throws a couple of errors that disappear when I remove that image from drawable folder and leave the spinner with the background by default.

I would like to know if someone could tell me how to set the image as spinner background without those errors appearing.

Here is my xml code:

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:background="@drawable/barraspinner" />
```

These are the errors that show me Android Studio:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: